# Digit Frequency Program (HackerRank)

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to compare each character of the given string with numbers 0 to 9, and on successful comparison, increment the count variable. Finally, printing the value of count variable for each of the numbers.
But these method isn't working out. Can't figure out why.

```
int main() {

    char *s;
    s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);

    int i,j,count=0;
    for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
    {   
        for(j=0;j<strlen(s);j++)
        {
            if(s[j]==i)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    printf("%d ",count);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not tag both C and C++ as the solutions will greatly differ. This code is clearly C so in this case the C++ tag is not relevant.

Comment: Rectified. Apologies!

Comment: The standard `%s` format for `scanf` reads space-delimited strings. And newline is a space. And if you're always allocating memory for `1024` characters, why not use an array (i.e. `char s[1024];`)? I suggest you invest in a couple of books about C, algorithms and data-structures, or better yet take a few classes about it, before going to online "competition" sites. Such sites are not learning or teaching resources, and shouldn't be used as such. First learn, then you can use them as *training* resources.

Comment: You need to be aware of the difference between `1` and `'1'`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The input part was already typed in on the website. My code started after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Finally, printing the value of count variable for each of the numbers.

So you need an array to store counters for each digit. It is strange that zero is excluded from counted digits.

In this if statement

```
if(s[j]==i)
```

you have to write at least

```
if( s[j] - '0' == i )
```

And moreover this loop

```
for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
```

also tries to count zeroes though you wrote that to count only digits 1-9 inclusively.

Your approach is inefficient because you are traversing the same character array several times. 
And there is no sense to allocate a character array dynamically.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { M = 9, N = 1024 };
    char s[N];
    s[0] = '\0';

    size_t counter[M] = { 0 };

    fgets( s, N, stdin );

    for ( const char *p = s; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( '0' < *p && *p <= '9' )
        {
            ++counter[*p - '0' - 1];
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%zu ", counter[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter for example a string like

```
12345678987654321246897531
```

then the output will be

```
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2
```

In fact the character array is redundant for this task. Moreover it restricts the length of the entered sequence of digits. You could write the program without using a character array. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { M = 9, N = 1024 };
    size_t counter[M] = { 0 };

    for ( int c; ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n'; )
    {
        if ( '0' < c && c <= '9' )
        {
            ++counter[c - '0' - 1];
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%zu ", counter[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You give your method but you don't tell him why his program don't work, so you don't answer to his original question

Comment: @Sunchock Reread one more my answer. It will be useful for you.

Comment: Instead of `'0' < *p && *p <= '9'`, why not use `isdigit(*p)`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think that it is more clear for the author of the question.:)

Answer (score 0):

In C a character value is a number, but it is not the number you are expecting here. When we have the character '2' and we check what it is equal to as a number we are really asking what the ASCII code of '2' is which in this case would be 50. You need to adjust your code so it converts the ASCII code into a numeric representation so 50 becomes 2. It is quite simple simply change your code so it looks like this

`if((s[j] - '0') == i){`

This works because the ASCII code of 0 is 48, the ASCII code of 1 is 49, etc etc.

TL;DR In C a character value is not equal to it's numeric value. You need to convert '5' to 5. To do this you adjust your code so you subtract the '0' character from your numeric character.

Comment: If you use character literals like `'0'` there is no need to even think about such magic numbers like ASCII value 50 etc.

Comment: @Gerhardh you are right, that is why in my code snippet I put '0'. I feel that it is important though as a developer to understand the ASCII codes and why we need to subtract '0' from our char.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(s[j]==i) <<<<<<<<<
   {
        count++;
   }
```

You are comparing the ordinal value of the character to an integer in the range 0 to 9. Which is not what you want.
You can convert a digit to int with this method:

```
char c = '5';
int x = c - '0';
```

So in your case it would be:

```
if(s[j] -'0' ==i)
{
    count++;
}
```